# UBUNTU is not prompting for password

Tags: 14.04, password

I am  using UBUNTU 14.04 on Sony vaio  computer. I'm dual booting with windows 8.1.

till now everything works fine but recently my OS(UBUNTU) is not prompting for password.

I am using gnome while that problem appears so i have changed to unity til that problem

occurs.

I've tried    sudo lightdm restart  but that didn't work. I've tried seahorse  but that

didn't  work.

how can I for  prompt for password again?

Answer (score 1):

Try to turn off Automatic Login in Settings > User Accounts

If you cannot find Settings menu from the graphical interface, try opening it from terminal with the `gnome-control-center` command.

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot the Computer with your Windows partition and shut it down normally. Then start the computer again with the Ubuntu partition. Sometimes when Windows isn't shut down properly it has some kind of lock or whatever on the files, that Ubuntu can't read them.

Comment: I already did that no use..

Comment: Then I'm out of answers :( sorry.

Answer (score 0):

open System Settings  and click on user accounts and click on your user name.

there you can see login options  you can find automatic login option just make it off then

it will prompt for password.